How to break the loop if iteration is between two members of a list
I have a list like this:
list1 = [
    'some',
    'thing',
    'is',
    'here',
    'dont',
    'care',
    'them',
    'The process completed',
    'process id: p1',
    'process id: p2',
    'Regards',
    'some',
    'thing',
    'is',
    'here',
    'dont',
    'care',
    'them',
    'The process completed',
    'process id: p12',
    'Regards',
]

I'm going to create a new list like this (expected output):
list3 = [
    'The process completed:\nprocess id: p1, process id: p2',
    'The process completed:\nprocess id: p12'
]

I'm going to find and save from The process completed until Regards (but the Regards itself is not considered).
I tried this:
new_list = []
new_str = ''
for l in list1:
    if l == 'The process completed':
        new_str += l
    new_str += l
    if l == 'Regards':
        new_list.append(new_str)
        new_str = ''
        pass

I know this is not right, but I thought like this as the logic:
if `l == The process completed`, then save from that string up to `Regards`, but not `Regards` itself.

Then find another `The process completed` and do the same.

How can I do that?

Using iterators:
list3 = []
it = iter(list1)
while 'The process completed' in it:
    list3.append('The process completed:\n' + ', '.join(iter(it.__next__, 'Regards')))

Attempt This Online!

Assuming every 'The process completed' has closing 'Regards' you can find the indices and slice the list
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(list1) if x in {'The process completed', 'Regards'}]
list3 = [f'{list1[indices[i]]}:\n{", ".join(list1[indices[i]+1:indices[i+1]])}' for i in range(0, len(indices), 2)]
print(list3)

Output
['The process completed:\nprocess id: p1, process id: p2',
 'The process completed:\nprocess id: p12']


Also assumes there are no extra 'Regards' elsewhere.

This doesn't really answer your direct question of breaking a loop, but it solves the high level requirement.

I'm going to find and save from "The process completed" until "Regards" [excluding "Regards"]

list1 = [
    'some',
    'thing',
    'is',
    'here',
    'dont',
    'care',
    'them',
    'The process completed',
    'process id: p1',
    'process id: p2',
    'Regards',
    'some',
    'thing',
    'is',
    'here',
    'dont',
    'care',
    'them',
    'The process completed',
    'process id: p12',
    'Regards',
]

e = 0
done = False
list3 = []
while not done:
    try:
        s = list1.index("The process completed", e)
        e = list1.index("Regards", s)
        ent = list1[s] + ":\n" + ', '.join(list1[s+1:e])
        list3.append(ent)
    except ValueError as e:
        done = True

print(list3)

Output
['The process completed:\nprocess id: p1, process id: p2', 'The process completed:\nprocess id: p12']

Other posts had this:
Explanation:
index() accepts a starting location (s, e). Search for the starting tag beginning at the previous ending tag (e), primed at 0. Then search for the ending tag starting at the current starting tag (s). Slice and join together the parts you want, append to list3.
Leverage the index()'s exception testing to end the loop.

I'd use while True: and break.

I didn't see @guy's solution...

@nocomment - yeah, I guess its my thread programming mentality...

inchman1900 posted a solution that ended with "handle the trailing comma". I get around this by using a "leading comma"
new_list = []
new_str = ''
for l in list1:
    if l == 'The process completed':
        new_str = l + ':\n'
        comma = ''     ### What to use for a comma
    elif l == 'Regards':
        new_list.append(new_str)
        new_str = ''
    elif new_str != "":
        new_str += comma + l   ### Prefix with a "comma"
        comma = ', '   ### Next time, we'll need a comma

Basically, you put the "comma" in front of new entries, but the "comma" is a blank string the first time.
The obvious issue is setting 'comma' to a constant on each iteration, however, I have found that many languages will optimize such an assignment. I don't know what Python does, but if this were C, that could be just ONE machine instruction. Compare that simple assignment per loop to the work needed to find the end of the string, test it for a comma, then remove it - I think the overhead of the constant assignment is much less.

You can achieve this by iterating over the list and identifying segments that start with "The process completed" and end before "Regards". The relevant strings within these segments can then be accumulated and formatted as desired.
list1 = [
    'some', 'thing', 'is', 'here', 'dont', 'care', 'them',
    'The process completed', 'process id: p1', 'process id: p2', 'Regards',
    'some', 'thing', 'is', 'here', 'dont', 'care', 'them',
    'The process completed', 'process id: p12', 'Regards',
]

list3 = []
new_str = ''
collecting = False

for l in list1:
    if l == 'The process completed':
        collecting = True
        new_str = l + ':\n' 

    elif l == 'Regards' and collecting:
        list3.append(new_str.strip())
        collecting = False

    elif collecting:
        new_str += l + ', ' if l.startswith('process id:') else ''

list3 = [s.rstrip(', ') for s in list3]

print(list3)

Explanation:
collecting: This flag indicates whether you're currently collecting strings for a segment.
new_str: This string accumulates the segment data between "The process completed" and "Regards".
Conditionals:
When you encounter "The process completed", you start collecting and initialize new_str.
You stop collecting when you hit "Regards" and save the accumulated data.
While collecting, relevant strings that start with "process id:" are added to new_str, with proper formatting.
I think this helps you

I don't know how you got your 3979 points, but here is the code:
new_list = []
new_str = ''

for l in list1:
    if l == 'The process completed':
        new_str = l + ':\n'
    elif l == 'Regards':
        new_list.append(new_str)
        new_str = ''
    elif new_str != "":
        new_str += l + ", "

I believe you can handle the trailing comma.

Better than handling the trailing comma would be to not create it in the first place.

Those points could come from different topics, languages, etc. OP might be a database expert.

I "solved" the trailing comma problem by using "leading commas".  I'll post an "answer" below...

Those points come from when I was young and had the ability to think and solve the problems. Someone has got this ability:(
